# Как перевести код с pyton на php

Tags: php, python, скрипт

Есть код на python

```
data = {"test": "123"}
digest = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(data).encode()).digest()
base64 = base64.b64encode(digest).decode("utf-8")
// base64 | FU/k0/TF9apOoP+3fRjXg1Kxe2ME5dD7vVOQgOip3LA=
```

Как его перевести на php?
Пишу такой код:

```
$data = ["test" => "123"];
$base64 = base64_encode(hash('sha256',json_encode($data),true));
// base64 | QPlNWg2hr7S0jLVHLdBEBxI9vWCgyKswzysAscnqQvQ=
```

Comment: `base64_encode(hash('sha256', json_encode(data), true))`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что в питоне `json.dumps` выдаёт строку `{"test": "123"}`, а в PHP `json_encode` выдаёт `{"test":"123"}` (без пробела). С т.з. JSON эти строки представляют одинаковый объект, то хеш от них очевидно разный. Далее возникает вопрос, зачем вообще вы считаете хеш от строки, т.е. какую задачу вы решаете.